# In PIE, what was the function of the suffix *-(ō)l?

Tags: etymology, proto-indo-european

For example, in the word:

*H₃nóbʰ-ōl /  *H₃ómbʰ-l̥ "navel" ([Wiktionary: Reconstruction:Proto-Indo-European/h₃nóbʰōl](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Indo-European/h%E2%82%83n%C3%B3b%CA%B0%C5%8Dl))

Comment: This archived discussion on Wiktionary contains some clues: While the suffix can be clearly reconstructed, its function was unknown three years ago: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction_talk:Proto-Indo-European/h%E2%82%83nob%CA%B0ilos#RFM_discussion:_May_2020%E2%80%93March_2021

Answer (score 1):

The answer below is about suffix `-l̥` but not the one in the word for navel (because of the difference in oblique cases), altough it is possible, they are related.

It is an old noun suffix, found in the most ancient words.

It is a variant of the [suffix `-r̥`](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Indo-European/-r%CC%A5). Many suffixes had `r` and `l` versions, with original form considered to be `-r-` (-tro-/-tlo-, -ter-/-tel-, etc). The suffix changed depending on case: in nominative it was `-r̥/-l̥` while in oblique cases it became `-n-/-en-`.

Examples include:

```
*sóh₂wl̥ (NOM) / *sh₂wéns (GEN) "Sun"
*wódr̥ (NOM) / *wédn̥s (GEN) "water"
*péh₂wr̥ (NOM) / *ph₂wéns (GEN) "fire"
```

Comment: Thank you for answering!